# Mac OS X startup manager always appears (option key inverted?)

Tags: macos, startup

I set up a fresh install of OS X 10.7.5 on a mid 2007's MacMini2,1 and installed my personal stuff like some components via Homebrew. 
After a few restarts it stopped booting automatically into my OS. The startup Manager always appears now where I can select the boot device. 
When I press the option-key during boot, everything is like normal. It seems like the option-key-function is inverted?!

Anybody else got this? How can I repair EFi?

Comment: If you enable the keyboard viewer ("Show Keyboard & character viewer in menu bar" in Keyboard system preferences) does it seem as if the option key is unresponsive, stuck or inverted?

Comment: No, nothing. When the system has booted, everything works like normal. The problem only appears at startup with or without a keyboard attached.

Comment: Did you try resetting NVRAM & SMC?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution was ridiculous... Really.
My MacMini got any signals from infrared like maybe only the light or any remote control or whatever in room. It works normal when I put anything on the infrared-receiver on my MacMini. The signal was like an option-keypress (menu on remote control)

Hope that helps people in future